# oracle 11g date function related -

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatetime

How do we come to know whether the given 2 digit year code(YY) is of 19XX or 20XX? For example if we type `07-apr-10`, then is `10` the year `1910` or `2010`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG202 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51076

Comment: You can't ever know for sure. Get whoever's supplied you with the data to be explicit.

Comment: I am with Ben here. 07-apr-10 could as well mean 07-apr-1710 depending on the context. This has nothing to do with databases. So yes, ask the one you get the dates from for rules on how to interpret the dates.

Comment: Simple - if the year was entered as "10", then it is the year 10 AD. Anything else is a hack. :)

Comment: ty...:-)@Ben@Thorsten Kettner@Jeffrey Kemp

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should be using the [`RR` datetime format element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215) to convert two-digit years to full years.

> If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
>
> - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
> - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 greater than the first 2 digits of the current year.
>
> If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then
>
> - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 less than the first 2 digits of the current year.
> - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.

I don't think you want `YY`, as it always fills the missing digits with ones from the current year. For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('98', 'YY'), 'YYYY') FROM dual; -- returns 2098, not 1998
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('9',  'Y'),  'YYYY') FROM dual; -- returns 2019
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('98', 'RR'), 'YYYY') FROM dual; -- returns 1998 (until we get to 2050)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry my client setting only had YY in it. After adding YYYY, I am getting below results. So looks like by default YY takes 20YY

```
 select to_date('7/10/15','DD/MM/YY') from dual;
 07-OCT-2015

 select to_date('7/10/15','DD/MM/YYYY')  from dual;
 07-OCT-0015
```

Comment: They might not be the "same" because your SQL client hides the full year from you, so you can't tell if they are the same.

Comment: Let's repeat the experiment with extract( year from to_date())

Comment: Yes. My bad. I changed the setting. Second query gives year as 0015. Editing the answer. Thanks for the hint with the client.

Answer (score 0):

To check this :

First of all you need to convert a CHAR with YY year format into a date:

```
TO_DATE('20-01-15','DD-MM-YY');
```

and after that immediately convert it back to CHAR, and see output, like below:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20-01-15','DD-MM-YY'),'YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: ty...:-)@Andrei Amarfii